# Using Java 8 stream methods to get a max value

Tags: java, methods, java-8, max, java-stream

I would like to get the max value out of a list using java 8 stream methods.

The structure is the following:

- I read a csv file and store the data of every line in a separate object of type `Round`.
- all these `Round` objects are stored in an `ArrayList` called `arrRound`
- all `Round` objects have a field: `List<Hit> hits`
- a `Hit` consists of 2 fields: `int numberOfGames` and `int prizeAmount`

```
public class Round{
    private List<Hits> hits; 
}
public class Hits{
    private int numberOfGames;
    private int prizeAmount;
}
```

---

What I would like to do is to iterate over all elements of `arrRound`, get their hits field's `getPrizeAmount()` method and get the max out of it.
I started as the following but can't seem to do it:

```
public class Main(){
    public void main(String[]args){
        List<Round> arrRound = getRoundFromCSV();
        int maxPrize = arrRound.stream()
                               .forEach(round -> {
                                 round.getHits()
                                      .forEach(hit -> hit.getPrizeAmount());
                                });
    }
}
```

and I am not able to call max() on the end of the statement.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve it by this way :

- iterate over the `Round` of the `list`
- change from `Round` object to its `List<Hit> hits`,
- use `flatMap` to go from `Stream<List<Hits>>` to `Stream<Hits>`
- change from `Hits` to its `prizeAmount` field
- get the `max` if exists
- if no max (like if list empty or else) return `-1`

---

So a solution using `Method reference`

```
int maxPrize = arrRoundarrRound.stream()                      // Stream<Round>
                               .map(Round::getHits)           // Stream<List<Hits>>
                               .flatMap(List::stream)         // Stream<Hits>
                               .mapToInt(Hit::getPrizeAmount) // IntStream
                               .max()                         // OptionalInt 
                               .orElse(-1);                   // int
```

With class `lambda` and `map + flatMap` in one :

```
int maxPrize = arrRoundarrRound.stream()    
                               .flatMap(round -> round.getHits().stream())
                               .mapToInt(hits -> hits.getPrizeAmount())
                               .max()                         
                               .orElse(-1);
```

Comment: a more readable solution --> `int maxPrize = arrRound.stream()
                           .map(Round::getHits)
                           .flatMap(List::stream)
                           .mapToInt(Hit::getPrizeAmount)
                           .max().orElse(-1);`. Although, it's a matter of preference to use method references or not ;-)

Comment: I think the original solution was more readable :) This just shows that readability is a subjective thing and it depends more on the reader, at least for these subtle cases.

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes sence now...
Need to check all methods more deeply one-by-one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatMap`:

```
int maxPrize = arrRound.stream() // Stream<Round>
                       .flatMap(r -> r.getHits().stream()) // Stream<Hit>
                       .mapToInt(Hit::getPrizeAmount) // IntStream
                       .max()
                       .orElse(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

using `reduce`

```
int max1 = arrRound.stream()
        .flatMap(r -> r.getHits().stream())
        .mapToInt(h -> h.getPrizeAmount())
        .reduce(Math::max) //returns OptionalInt
        .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

or

```
int max2 = arrRound.stream()
        .flatMap(r -> r.getHits().stream())
        .mapToInt(h -> h.getPrizeAmount())
        .reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Math::max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `forEach` is a terminal operation.
And after you call the `forEach` on a stream the stream terminates and  can't be used again.

Answer (score 0):

using `Comparator`:

```
int max2 = arrRound.stream()
            .flatMap(round -> round.getHits().stream())
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Hits::getPrizeAmount))
            .map(Hits::getPrizeAmount)
            .orElse(-1);
```