# Finding max using lambda java

Tags: java

Here is my code :

```
public static void Max(List<List<String>> data) {
    data.forEach(d -> String max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(d.getMax(5))));
}
```

The result I get:

```
70
75
76
```

How can I get only the maximum number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Java 8 stream methods to get a max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608983/using-java-8-stream-methods-to-get-a-max-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Comparator.comparing` to compare the 2nd index and parse as Integer when compare then get the second index element from the list.

```
String res = Collections.max(data, 
               Comparator.comparing(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.get(2)))).get(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

A more simple way:

```java
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.get(i).size(); j++) {
                max = Integer.max(Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).get(j)), max);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
```

This way we comb through every member of each list and by invoking `max()` we get the max number, which is then displayed in the console.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response..really appreciate it :)