# Returning the maximum value from a list using stream API

Tags: arraylist, java-stream

i have Response class which has limit parameter . when i make api calls different response objects are returned with the limit values which are stored in an Arraylist .

```
List<Response> values = new Arraylist<>();

    class Response{
    private int limit;
}
```

Now i want to iterate though the list of Responses and get the maximum limit using streams API .

Comment: See `Stream.max(Comparator)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Java 8 stream methods to get a max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608983/using-java-8-stream-methods-to-get-a-max-value)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use something like this

```
int maxLimit = values.stream()
                .mapToInt(Response::getLimit)
                .max()
                .orElse(...); // default value or throw exception
```

Here is the link to the article https://www.baeldung.com/java-collection-min-max

Comment: thus will return the max limit, not the response with max limit.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways of doing it: the most compact one is `stream.max()`. Alternatively, you can use `collect` or `reduce`, in a similar way:

```
Optional<Response> opt1 = values.stream()
        .max(
                Comparator.comparing(Response::getLimit)
        );

Optional<Response> opt2 = values.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.maxBy(
                Comparator.comparingInt(Response::getLimit)
        ));

Optional<Response> opt3 = values.stream()
        .reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy(
                Comparator.comparingInt(Response::getLimit)
        ));
```